# How to fire a signal with QMetaObject::activate

Tags: qt

I found an [interesting article on how to impement QObject with dynamic properties](https://machinekoder.com/creating-qml-properties-dynamically-runtime-c/) (see C++ class DynamicObject). The code from the article works fine, the properties of DynamicObject are get and set successfully from both C++ and QML, but the only thing I cannot figure out is how to fire dynamic signals.

I tried to fire "nameChanged()" signal with the following code:

```
bool DynamicObject::emitDynamicSignal(char *signal, void **arguments)
{
    QByteArray theSignal = QMetaObject::normalizedSignature(signal);
    int signalId = metaObject()->indexOfSignal(theSignal);

    if (signalId >= 0)
    {
        QMetaObject::activate(this, metaObject(), signalId, arguments);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

myDynamicObject->emitDynamicSignal("nameChanged()", nullptr);
```

the index of the signal is found and signalId is assigned to 5, but the signal is not fired. But if I do, for example,

```
myDynamicObject->setProperty("name", "Botanik");
```

the property is changed and the signal is fired successfully.

What is wrong in my code? What should I pass as 'arguments' parameter of QMetaObject::activate ?

**EDIT1:**

The full source code is temporarily available [here](https://slogpost.ru/temp/DynamicObject.zip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signal is also a method. You can invoke it from the *meta object*.

So, replace your line `QMetaObject::activate(...)` by:

`metaObject()->method(signalId).invoke(this);`

And let Qt handles the call to `activate()`.

There is also an issue in `DynamicObject::qt_metacall()`: you are handling only `QMetaObject::ReadProperty` and `QMetaObject::WriteProperty` calls.

You have to add `QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod` if you want to emit your signal.

Comment: Tried this but with no success, the signal is not fired, see the full source code https://slogpost.ru/temp/DynamicObject.zip . There is no PDB files for MSVC2017 here https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/5.12.2/ so I cannot debug invoke(this).

Comment: I've updated my answer: check your `DynamicObject::qt_metacall()`. There are missing cases.